# how hoisting works ? difference between function and variable

Tags: javascript, hoisting

may i know how this code execute?

```js
function scope() {
  return hosting;

  function hosting() {
    var hosting = '15';
  }
  var hosting = 12;

}

console.log(typeof scope())
```

here this code return function, we now js engine will move the declaration to top so we get function,

```js
function scope() {
  return hosting;

  var hosting = 12;
}

console.log(typeof scope())
```

but now why its not return number?, but i know we need to use let to avoid this

Comment: It's [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) (not hosting). But there is really no good reason to still use `var` instead of `let` and `const`.

Comment: oops my bad, i am stuck with legacy code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn`t return number 12 because **hoisting** works only for declarating the actual variable, not to assign it a value.

This means that your code looks like this for compilator:

```
function scope() {
    var hosting;
    return hosting;

    hosting=12;
```

}

Also please remember that everything after `return` is not executed.

Comment: great, but in fn, we get the entire function before return statement correct?

Comment: @SelvaGanapathi I didn`t understand what you mean ?

Comment: I got it dude..

Answer (score 1):

When JS hoists a function it will know to return the actual function, but when it's a variable declaration it hoists it with `undefined` as value. And unless the actual line of assignment is reached, it won't have the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the console.log to return number you should put the hosting declaration above the return like that:

```js
function scope() {
  var hosting = 12;
  return hosting;

 
}

console.log(typeof scope())
```

Comment: dude thats i know,

Comment: I thought that was what you were asking for , maybe I did  not understand your question

Comment: look the below comment, tht what i am asking for